# Atribuir Strings a uma Lista de Datas

Tags: java

Preciso atribuir para cada dia de uma lista de datas de um período de intervalo, uma determinada String dentre três possíveis (Turma A, Turma B, Turma C), de modo que o resultado seja sequencial até preencher todas as datas da lista.

Segue código feito até agora....

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class CalcularDatas {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String[] myArray = {"Turma A", "Turma B", "Turma C"};
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(myArray));

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dt1 = df.parse ("01/10/2016"); // Data inicial
        Date dt2 = df.parse ("10/10/2016"); // 
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime (dt1);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime (dt2);
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        for (Calendar cal = cal1; cal.compareTo (cal2) <= 0; cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 1)) {
            System.out.println (df.format (cal.getTime())+ arrayList);
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> 01/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   02/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   03/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   04/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   05/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   06/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   07/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   08/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   09/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   10/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]
>   11/10/2016[Turma A, Turma B, Turma C]

Modo esperado:

> 01/10/2016 Turma A
>   02/10/2016 Turma B
>   03/10/2016 Turma C
>   04/10/2016 Turma A
>   05/10/2016 Turma B
>   06/10/2016 Turma C
>   07/10/2016 Turma A
>   08/10/2016 Turma B
>   09/10/2016 Turma C
>   10/10/2016 Turma A
>   11/10/2016 Turma B

Answer (score 3):

Se você manda imprimir `arrayList`, obviamente ele irá imprimi-la inteira. A solução é usar um iterador, ir incrementando-o modularmente e imprimir apenas a posição desse índice:

```
int i = 0;
for (Calendar cal = cal1; cal.compareTo(cal2) <= 0; cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)) {
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()) + " " + arrayList.get(i));
    i = (i + 1) % 3;
}
```

Comment: Interessante solução! +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Uma das possíveis soluções é utilizar [**`Iterator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) sob a sua `ArrayList`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String[] myArray = {"Turma A", "Turma B", "Turma C"};
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(myArray));

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dt1 = df.parse ("01/10/2016"); // Data inicial
    Date dt2 = df.parse ("10/10/2016"); // 
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime (dt1);
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime (dt2);
    cal2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    //cria o iterator sob o arraylist
    Iterator<String> it = arrayList.iterator();

    for (Calendar cal = cal1; cal.compareTo (cal2) <= 0; cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 1)) {
        //checa se o iterator já chegou ao fimm
        //se sim, o reinicia
        if(!it.hasNext()){
            it = arrayList.iterator();      
        }
        // next() exibe o item seguinte do arraylist
        System.out.println (df.format (cal.getTime()) + it.next());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 01/10/2016 Turma A
>   02/10/2016 Turma B
>   03/10/2016 Turma C
>   04/10/2016 Turma A
>   05/10/2016 Turma B
>   06/10/2016 Turma C
>   07/10/2016 Turma A
>   08/10/2016 Turma B
>   09/10/2016 Turma C
>   10/10/2016 Turma A
>   11/10/2016 Turma B

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/qfvbOF)

Comment: Ambos os códigos funcionaram perfeitamente. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @Mecsr você pode aceitar uma das respostas, clicando no ✅  e também pode votar nas duas, clicar na seta para cima de ambas.

Comment: E se eu quiser associar um horário a cada turma. Essa seria a melhor maneira? Teria com juntar os dois arrays em um só?

Comment: @Mecsr Quer salvar essa saida como um terceiro Array?

Comment: E se eu quiser associar um horário a cada turma. Teria como juntar os arrays?
String[] myArrayTurma = {"Turma A", "Turma B", "Turma C"};
String[] myArrayHorario = {"08:00 às 12:00", "12:00 às 18:00", "18:00 às 24:00"};
List<String> arrayListHorario = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(myArrayHorario));
                                                                               if(!iteratorHorario.hasNext()){
iteratorHorario = arrayListHorario.iterator();
}
System.out.println (df.format (cal.getTime()) + " " + iteratorTurma.next() + " " + iteratorHorario.next());

Comment: A ideia seria essa, salvar a saida como um terceiro Array. Porem os horarios nao seriam fixos, nao seria o mesmo horario sempre para cada Turma. Esses horários seriam criados de acordo com que cada Turma fosse criada. Quando criar a turma 1 vou informar qual sera o horario dessa turma, quando criar a turma 2 informarei o seu horario e assim por diante.... A ideia seria essa.

Comment: @Mecsr deixa eu te dar uma sugestão, ao inves de ficar criando inumeros arrays, porque não cria um [POJO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects) de turma? Assim, você concentra todas as informações relativas a turma numa classe, e salva cada turma como se fosse um objeto, exemplo:http://pastebin.com/4Cu8vVQT